# Im trying to to figure out what I need to write on sql command oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

For every customer that lives in Florida, list customer number, last name, first name,
and region.

Comment: Please include the table(s) you are working with, some example data to demonstrate the use-cases you're facing, the desired results you expect from that example data, and, most of all, the query or queries you've tried so far and details on why they did not give what you wanted/expected. You may also benefit from reading this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are trying to get the information from a table called "table".

```sql
select customer_number,
       last_name,
       first_name,
       region
from table
where city = 'Florida'
```

Comment: It says missing left parenthesis. And yes I'm trying to find which tables it is. I think it's in DEMO_STATES since i found florida there. But customer number i don't know where it is.